# How to efficiently compute all trees with n leaves and 2n-2 nodes

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics, trees

I would like to efficiently compute all trees with n leaves and 2n-2 nodes. This is equivalent to trees with n leaves where all interior (non-leaf) vertices are trivalent.

The input should be the number n and the output should be a list consisting of graphs.

For example, the output for 6 would be:

[image]

Ideally I would like to be able to compute up to n=19 or 20. This would give [11020 trees](http://oeis.org/A129860).

Right now I have an extremely slow method which starts from a tree with n leaves and one central node, and then "grows" the interior edges in all ways, and then removes the isomorphic / redundant trees in the end. This allows me to go up to n=10.

**Update:**
Here is the best I have come up with so far...

First there is a command for making a tree object into a graph object (see another one of my questions).

```
    makeTree[nodes_] := 
     Module[{counter = 0}, 
      traverse[h_[childs___]] := 
       With[{id = 
          counter}, {UndirectedEdge[id, ++counter], 
           traverse[#]} & /@ {childs}];
      traverse[_] := Sequence[];
      Graph[#] &@Flatten[traverse[nodes]]]
```

Then I make all *rooted* trees using Groupings:

```
   AllRootedTrees[n_] := 
   makeTree /@ TreeForm /@ Groupings[Table[a, n - 1], {2, Orderless}]
```

Then, I remove the isomorphic duplicates:

```
  AllTrees[n_] := 
  DeleteDuplicates[AllRootedTrees[n], IsomorphicGraphQ[#1, #2] &]
```

The last step is probably very inefficient but this is the fastest method I have so far.

(the computation for 15 trees takes 25.2 seconds)

Comment: It seems that you have a non-recursive algorithm to generate the trees -- can you make it recursive? Meaning, can you turn your current algorithm to find n-level trees from (n-1)-levels trees? Can you post your code?

Comment: For the last step, use `DeleteDuplicatesBy[trees, CanonicalGraph]`. It will be much faster because it does not do pairwise comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

I think your code is good.  The serious bottleneck is removing isomorphic duplicates.  The efficient way to do this is

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[graph, CanonicalGraph]
```

[`CanonicalGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CanonicalGraph.html) will canonically order/label vertices, so that it always maps isomorphic graphs to the same expression (which is also a `Graph`).

With this sole change,

```
AllTrees[n_] := DeleteDuplicatesBy[AllRootedTrees[n], CanonicalGraph]
```

the timing is

```
AllTrees[20] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
(* {39.6098, 11020} *)
```