# Enumerating unlabeled phylogenetic trees

Tags: combinatorics

The following code comes from [OEIS A000311](https://oeis.org/A000311) which is labeled phylogenetic trees. The function `mtot` enumerates the labeled trees.

```
size=4;
sps[{}] := {{}};
sps[set : {i_, ___}] := 
  Join @@ Function[s, Prepend[#, s] & /@ sps[Complement[set, s]]] /@ 
    Cases[Subsets[set], {i, ___}];
mtot[m_] := 
  Prepend[Join @@ 
    Table[Tuples[mtot /@ p], {p, 
      Select[sps[m], 1 < Length[#] < Length[m] &]}], m];
Table[Length[mtot[Range[n]]], {n, 1, size}]

(*Labeled trees*)
mtot[Range[4]]
>{{1,2,3,4},{{1},{2},{3,4}},{{1},{2,3},{4}},{{1},{2,4},{3}},{{1},{2,3,4}},
{{1},{{2},{3,4}}},{{1},{{2,3},{4}},{{1},{{2,4},{3}}},{{1,2},{3},{4}},
{{1,2},{3,4}},{{1,3},{2},{4}},{{1,3},{2,4}},{{1,4},{2},{3}},{{1,4},{2,3}},
{{1,2,3},{4}},{{{1},{2,3}},{4}},{{{1,2},{3}},{4}},{{{1,3},{2}},{4}},
{{1,2,4},{3}},{{{1},{2,4}},{3}},{{{1,2},{4}},{3}},{{{1,4},{2}},{3}},
{{1,3,4},{2}},{{{1},{3,4}},{2}},{{{1,3},{4}},{2}},{{{1,4},{3}},{2}}}
```

What I need is an fast method of enumerating unlabeled trees. See [OEIS A000669](https://oeis.org/A000669) While the labeled trees can be used to find the unlabeled trees, it is very inefficient.

```
(*Unlabeled trees*)
{{o,o,o,o},{o,o,{o,o}},{o,{o,o,o}},{o,{o,{o,o}}},{{o,o},{o,o}}}
```

```
(*Number of first 6 enumerated labeled trees*)
{1,1,4,26,236,2752,39208,660032};

(*Number of first 6 enumerated unlabeled trees*)
{1,1,2,5,12,33,90,261};
```

Comment: Can you clarify what a "phylogenetic tree" means in this context? I assume it means a rooted tree, which can be encoded as a directed tree with edges oriented away from the root? Is your problem equivalent to finding all non-isomorphic directed trees on $n$ vertices?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "enumerating"? Do you mean merely counting (the word is sometimes used in this sense in math) or generating each and every instance (which is the more general meaning)?

Comment: If we only wanted to generate unlabelled undirected trees, we could use the `geng` utility from [the nauty suite](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/). It can generate all unlabelled graphs with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, with certain constraints. If we want trees, we can ask for _connceted_ graphs with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges. For example, with $n=7$, use `Import["!geng 7 6 -c", "Graph6"]`. You may need to put the absolute path to `geng` for your system.

Comment: Getting directed trees from this is not entirely trivial. For each undirected tree, we can orient edges away from each vertex, obtaining $n$ directed trees. However, some of these will still be isomorphic, and will need to be filtered out. With this method, I get this for 4 vertices: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc8B8.png These are 4 trees, but you claim 5. What is missing? There are no other directed out-trees on 4 vertices, only these.

Comment: For your convenience, implementation using my IGraph/M package: `Function[n, 
 Catenate[
  Function[tree, 
    DeleteDuplicatesBy[IGOrientTree[tree, #] & /@ VertexList[tree], 
     CanonicalGraph]] /@ 
   IGImport[
    "!/opt/local/bin/geng " <> IntegerString[n] <> " " <> 
     IntegerString[n - 1] <> " -c", "Nauty"]]]` Remember to edit the path to `geng` for your system.

Comment: @Szabolcs To my understanding, the phylogenetic tree mentioned by OP contains no nodes with degree=2 except the root, and here $n$ is the number of leaves.

Comment: That makes sense but this should be clarified in the post.

Comment: Related, as it deals with constraints on the degrees of internal vertices: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/234476/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to avoid "collisions" when building unlabeled trees from subtrees, and naively tried wrapping your functions with `DeleteDuplicates`.

```
spsu[{}] := {{}};
spsu[set_] := spsu[set] =
  DeleteDuplicates@(Sort/@(Join@@Function[s, Prepend[#, s] & /@ spsu[Table[a,Length@set-Length@s]]] /@ 
    (Table[a,#]&/@Range@Length@set)));

mtotu[m_] := mtotu[m]=
  DeleteDuplicates@(Sort/@(Prepend[Join @@ 
    Table[Tuples[mtotu /@ p], {p, 
      Select[spsu[m], 1 < Length[#] < Length[m] &]}], m]));
```

and the performance is not too bad,

```
Table[Length[mtotu[Table[a,n]]], {n, 1, 14}]//Timing
(*{0.182161, {1, 1, 2, 5, 12, 33, 90, 261, 766, 2312, 7068, 21965, 
  68954, 218751}}*)
```

comparing with the labeled ones,

```
Table[Length[mtot[Range[n]]], {n, 1, 8}]//Timing
(*{17.6373, {1, 1, 4, 26, 236, 2752, 39208, 660032}}*)
```

Here the standard trick

```
foo[x_]:=foo[x]=...
```

is to memorize old results of recurrsion.

---

[image]